# bootstrap multiselect checkbox behave like radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap multiselect which contains 7 checkbox items.
For 3 of them (all, resolved and open) I need them to act as a radio button:
When I select resolved then all and open must deselect.
When I select all then resolved and open must deselect.
When I select open then all and resolved must deselect.
Is it possible to achieve that without breaking the multiselect in multiple menus?

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sp3L1yz3/

I tried with 'onchange' but the logic is incorrect as it does not know the item that was just clicked and running a each make the select/deselect work only from top to bottom items:

```
onChange: function(option, checked) {
var selectedOptions = $('#menu option:selected');
  $('#menu option:selected').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().indexOf("resolved") > -1) {
      $('#menu').multiselect('deselect', 'all');
      $('#menu').multiselect('deselect', 'open');
      $('#menu').multiselect('select', 'resolved');
    }
    if ($(this).val().indexOf("open") > -1) {
      $('#menu').multiselect('deselect', 'all');
      $('#menu').multiselect('deselect', 'resolved');
      $('#menu').multiselect('select', 'open');
    }
    if ($(this).val().indexOf("all") > -1) {
      $('#menu').multiselect('select', 'all');
      $('#menu').multiselect('deselect', 'resolved');
      $('#menu').multiselect('deselect', 'open');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: looking at the markup created by bootstrap, this seems easier to implement without it, using regular check boxes. Group the check boxes and deselect siblings when one is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your options should be contained within `<optgroup>` tags, like this:

```
<div class="selectdiv">
   <select name="menu[]" id="menu" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
      <optgroup label="filter one">
         <option value='all' selected='selected'>all</option>
         <option value='resolved'>resolved</option>
         <option value='open'>open</option>
         <option value='other1'>other1</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label='filter two'>
          <option value='one'>1</option>
          <option value='ten'>10</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label='filter three'>
          <option value='three'>three</option>
      </optgroup>
   </select>
</div>
```

When you have this structure, you can implement what you are looking for in the onchange method like so:

```
$('#menu').multiselect({
    maxHeight: 400,
    numberDisplayed: 1,
    onChange: function(option, checked) {
                var values = [];
                var optGroupLabel = $(option).parent().attr('label');
                $('#menu optGroup[label="'+optGroupLabel+'"] option').each(function() {
                   if ($(this).val() !== option.val()) {
                      values.push($(this).val());
                   }
                });
                $('#menu').multiselect('deselect', values);
    }
})
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/z8e5hrwq/2/).